# How to query multiple entities with a single QueryExpression

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I am trying to run a microsoft dynamics crm 4.0 query. This works as expected when I generate a QueryExpression for "ONE" specific entity as I had done before. The issue however is how do i define more than one entity so i can apply logic that i have in  another method? An example or illistration would be helpful.

so what i have is in this format:

```
static BusinessEntityCollection GetData(CrmService service)
{
    cols = new ColumnSet();
    cols.Attributes = new string[] { "x", "y", "z"};

    FilterExpression filter = new FilterExpression();
    filter.FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.And;

    QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression();
    query.EntityName = EntityName.incident.ToString();

    // i am trying to add something like the below
    query.EntityName = EntityName.account.toString();

    query.ColumnSet = cols;
    query.Criteria = filter;

    return service.RetrieveMultiple(query);
}
```

The restriction I am facing is I can only query one entity and I need a solution or workaround to access and query multiple entities. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Query multiple entities at once or one after another?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple answer: you can't. You could only query one entity at one time.

> A query expression is used for single-object searches, for example, to search for all accounts that match certain search criteria.

See how to [build queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb928429.aspx).
You have to combine multiple requests for the entities you would like to get.

The same restriction exists for FetchXML. It is basically the serialized form of a [`QueryExpression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb929258.aspx). See [how to use FetchXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb928434.aspx)

Comment: Ok Thanks. From what i've been trying to dig up, a workaround seems to involve using fetchxml. what are your thoughts on that?